# Create a directory when the file with that name exists

Tags: php, file, mkdir

I have a function for my code editor project that takes some long path and creates appropriate directory or file with it
example :

`create_file( '/home/me/' , 'dir/file.txt' )` this creates a file called file.txt along with dir directory if not existing.

The problem is that the function gives an error saying `Warning: mkdir(): File exists` when I am making a directory called `home/me/dir`

( there is file called `/home/me/dir` )

here's the function

isn't there a way to make the directory with same name?

```
function create_file(string $path , string $filename) :bool {
    
            $return = false;
    
            $full_path = '/' . $path .'/'.$filename;
            
            if( !file_exists($full_path) && $this::is_within_allowed_path($path) && $this->is_allowed('/'.$path) && in_array( 'c' , $this->permissions('/'.$path) )) {
    
                $path = realpath('/'.$path);
                $parts = explode('/', trim($filename) );
                $fileName = array_pop($parts);
    
                $dir_to_make = '/' . $path .'/' . implode( '/' , array_filter( $parts ) );
                
                if( !is_dir( $dir_to_make ) ) mkdir( $dir_to_make , 0777 , true );
    
                if( trim($fileName) !== '' ) file_put_contents( $dir_to_make . '/' . $fileName , '' );
                
                $return = true;
    
            }
    
    
            return $return;
        }
```

I know I can do `file_exists()` but that won't solve anything

Comment: You can't create a directory and a file with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: It looks like there's already a _file_ (not directory) at the path you're trying to create a dir at. As @Olivier said, it is not possible to create a dir _and_ a file with the same name at the same path. If this is not intended, something with your logic might be wrong (add some debug output perhaps). If you're sure what you're doing, you can also try to delete the file before creating the dir. (And, for reasons of security, double-check that your allowed-checks do really work under any circumstances. ^^)

Comment: ++ You can add a timestamp when saving to make it unique. In DB, save both the original file name and the stored file name.

Comment: `isn't there a way to make the directory with same name?`...no. If there's a file named `/home/example` and you then create a directory also called `/home/example`, how do you expect that the operating system could tell them apart?? If, next time you provided that path, how should it know if you're referring to the file or the directory, if they both have the same name? I don't think you've thought this through.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take it by steps.

1. The name already exists in the same directory.
2. It appears that the conflicting file does not have an extension

So I suggest this algo

1. if file exist *rename by adding extension or something*
2. Create your directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).